# Joining Census block data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, census, arcgis-10.5

I know I'm probably missing something very basic, but I've been trying to join census block data together. The table contained within the block shapefile contains a field called GEOID10, which has concatenated the state, county, tract and block fields together.  I have downloaded a table from the american factfinder that contains the total population for each block from the 2010 census and it contains a field called Id2 which has the same concatenated field as GEOID10.  However, when I try to join the 2 together, ArcGIS won't give me Id2 as a field to base the join on when I choose GEOID10 as the field to use from the layer.  Any idea why this is?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.5

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the text justification within the GEOID10 and Id2 cells I would bet that the former are defined as integer and the latter as text.

For fields to be used as join fields they must be of the same type.

Comment: That's what I thought. I could swear I checked that and tried to make them both the same type but I'll have to check again.