# Mapping values by Census Tract - California

Tags: qgis

I was able to map values by county in California, but I am trying to map by census tract. I downloaded the census tract file from census bureau and it shows 8,041 values. For the values, I pulled in the census block. How do I get the census block to match up to the cb_2017_06_tract_500k shapefile? The values in this attribute table are StateF, CountyFP, TractCE, AFFGEOID, GEOID, NAME, LSAD, ALAND, and AWATER.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining Census block data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254265/joining-census-block-data)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this answers my questions. This is for ArcGIS and my census block data returned by the Bing API software does not match the GEOID.

Comment: blocks and tracts are different things, which do you want?

Comment: I am trying to map census tracts.

Answer (score 2):

Census Blocks roll up to Tracts via the TRACTCE column, which is present in both tables. Here are census tracts (black outline and labeled with TRACTCE) and the underlying Blocks (symbolized by their corresponding TRACTCE which relates to the Tract they fall within):

[image]

If you have data for Census Blocks and want to map the data at the Tract level, you'll have to summarize and group that column by TRACTCE, then you can join it back to the Census Tracts by the TRACTCE.

Comment: Thank you. I only have the TRACTCE column in the shapefile I pulled from Census. I pulled in average distances using the BING API software and do not have the TRACTCE column, but do have Census Blocks that we pulled in. If a census block is 60190054081005, is it safe to say the Census Tract is 0054.08?

Comment: Yes - the GEOID of the tract matches the GEOID10 of the block - BUT - be careful you don't lose the leading 0's of the columns! Those columns should all have leading 0's so the GEOID/GEOID10 is really 060190054081005

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Sure thing! Hope it works, get in touch if you have any other issues.